# What does this Java for loop termination condition mean?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am wondering if anyone here knows what the **termination condition** in
the following for loop is supposed to mean.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << Level; i++) {
...
}
```

Comment: `<<` is a bitwise operator. it multiplies by 2 Level times.

Answer (score 8):

`<<` shifts the bits of the first operand `n` times to the left, where `n` is the second operand.

Therefore `1 << Level` shifts the single `1` bit of the number `1` `Level` times to the left, which is equivalent to calculating 2 ^ Level.

So `i < 1 << Level` is equivalent to `i < Math.pow(2,Level)`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply stated

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << Level; i++) {
...
}
```

is equal to

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2,Level); i++) {
...
}
```

So the for loop will run for **"Math.pow(2,Level)"** times since you are counting from 0 to Math.pow(2,Level)-1.

if Level = 2 then the loop is

```
for(int i =0;i<4;i++){}
```

if Level = 3 then the loop is

```
for(int i =0;i<8;i++){}
```

if Level = 5 then the loop is

```
for(int i =0;i<32;i++){}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers it might help putting parenthesis around the expression if that is unclear

```
for (int i = 0; i < (1 << Level); i++) {
...
}
```

Also since `Level` is a variable it is suggested to have a small letter i.e. `level` unless it is a constant, then it should be `LEVEL`. And I think in general that readability > performance (if it is even a problem?). So `Math.pow(2,Level)` is much more easy to understand if you are not a low level programmer, looks much more like Java than C.